# How come my count() passes evaluation?

Tags: sql

I am fairly new at SQL and I am trying to create a query that tries to determine in which countries only 3 specific languages (spanish,italian,german) are spoken and no other languages.

```
select country
from langusage
group by country
having count(case when language in ('spanish','german','italian') then 1 else 5 end)=3
```

The output are all countries that have at least 1 of the aforementioned languages . How come they pass the '=3' test?

Comment: What are you expecting that count statement inside the `having` clause to do? The count will return 1 or 5, x number of times. You are counting the number of times it returns a value, but what's the 1 and 5 for in the case statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `count(1)` = `count(5)`.  `count()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.

You intend `sum()`:

```
select country
from langusage
group by country
having sum(case when iso in ('spanish', 'german', 'italian') then 1 else 5 end) = 3
```

Comment: Can someone explain to me what the case statement is for? Why 1 or 5?

Comment: @Charleh . . . The OP is just trying to put in values where the three languages will add up to 3, but nothing else does.

Comment: Could you explain the count(1)=count(5) ?
As for your answer, so the iso in(...) doesn't actually achieve anything, it is never evaluated against?

Comment: So why not just use 0?

Comment: @Charleh . . . Because then another language might be included.  `'Japanese'` could be a fourth language, and the OP doesn't want that.

Comment: Still doesn't make much sense - 5 is a random pick, I'd have just used 0: `case when column in (values) then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: Because if it is 0 ,than there is the possibility of a country having other languages next to the ones I gave. I don't want this, because of this I use 5